# Can I use different authentications for different directory in the same website solution?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I've a website solution separated into two parts - one part is for clients and the other is for service administrators. For the former I would like to use the integrated Form Authentication and for the latter Windows Azure Active Directory that syncs with the on-premise AD server.

Is it possible to specify two directories (locations) that use Form Authentication and Azure AD respectively?

PS: A similar example would be the Windows Azure Management portal, which allows you to log in either with an organizational account either with a Microsoft account.

I guess one solution might be using the "location" tag in Web.config and disabling the inheritance of authentication mode, though I haven't figured out how to get it working up till now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can define a web.config with the right authentication mechanism for each module then you should be able to achieve what you want.  Note that the logins for the Azure Portal are always claims-based regardless of source (organisational or Microsoft Account).

Comment: Thx for your answer.:) Yet I found that I could not define the authentication method in web.config of subfolder other than on the application level. Now I'm trying to add another project as a virtual directory into the existing one, which is really a mess.